# Javascript date conversion, sorting and display

Tags: javascript, date-format

I have a string of data that I need to convert, sort and display on the frontend using javascript.

**Data is in this format**
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss  event title here

**Example of feed:**
2011-04-19 00:00:00 event1 title here
2011-04-22 00:00:00 event2 title here
2011-05-25 00:00:00 event3 title here
2011-04-13 00:00:00 event4 title here
2011-12-13 00:00:00 event5 title here

**Need it to convert date format, display sorted by date, omitting events prior to current date (current date being 04-21-2011):**

Example of desired list:
04-22-2011 event2 title here
05-25-2011 event3 title here
12-13-2011 event5 title here

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what's your question?  Have you tried something that doesn't work or are you looking for advice on a general approach?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a homework you are getting us to do :P, give me some time I'll hook you up with something.

```
var dateRE = /^(\d{2})[\/\- ](\d{2})[\/\- ](\d{4})/;
function dmyOrdA(a, b){
a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
if (a>b) return 1;
if (a <b) return -1;
return 0; }
function dmyOrdD(a, b){
a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
if (a>b) return -1;
if (a <b) return 1;
return 0; }
function mdyOrdA(a, b){
a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
if (a>b) return 1;
if (a <b) return -1;
return 0; }
function mdyOrdD(a, b){
a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
if (a>b) return -1;
if (a <b) return 1;
return 0; }

dateArray = new Array('15/10/2000','28/05/1999',
'17/09/2005','06/12/2004','02/01/1998');
dateArray.sort( dmyOrdA );
document.write('Ascending : ' + dateArray + '<br />');
```

Now this is only a way to sort date, use this logic to adapt it for your need.
There are a couple of things you could do, possibly building object for your event to keep them tied with the dates as the sort goes through.

[Date sort from about.com](http://javascript.about.com/library/blsort3.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your posts, I'll give these a try.  I'm on the design side and have just enough coding and javascript knowledge to get in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Making some plugs here, but they may help:

The date-parsing and manipulation can be handled by my [DateExtensions](http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/) component.  The management of the list of dates (sorting) would be easily handled by my [ObCollectionOrdered](http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_obcollectionordered/) component.

There are examples of both that should help.

Depending on the circumstances these may be using a sledge-hammer to kill a fly, but they will abstract nearly all the complexity away from the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to implement a function which performs these tasks:

1. **Parsing the input**: the string must be parsed into a list of objects with "date" and "title" properties.  Try matching the "YYYY-MM-DD" date format with a regular expression and building a Date object with its constructor.
2. **Filtering the data**: the objects should be rejected if older than the current time and sorted by date in increasing order (oldest to newest).  Dates can be compared and lists can be sorted natively in JavaScript.
3. **Formatting the output**: the objects should be returned as a list of strings with the desired date format.  Try outputting the date by building a string from its month, date, and year getters.

You could, of course, use libraries for various tasks like date handling but using pure JavaScript should be simple enough.  For example:

```
<script language="javascript">
  var parseFeed = function(str, now) {
    var regex=/^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d) (.*)$/
      , input=str.split(/\n/).sort(), len=input.length
      , output=[], now=now||new Date(), d, m;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
      if (m = input[i].match(regex)) {
        d = new Date(m[1], m[2]-1, m[3], m[4], m[5], m[6]);
        if (d >= now) {
          output.push([m[2], m[3], m[1]].join('-') + ' ' + m[7]);
        }
      }
    }
    return output; // An array of sorted, yet-to-come, formatted events.
  };
  var input = ""
    + "2011-02-19 00:00:00 event0 title here\n"
    + "2011-04-19 00:00:00 event1 title here\n"
    + "2011-04-22 00:00:00 event2 title here\n"
    + "2011-05-25 00:00:00 event3 title here\n"
    + "2011-04-13 00:00:00 event4 title here\n"
    + "2011-12-13 00:00:00 event5 title here\n";
  var april12 = new Date(2011, 3, 21)
    , output = parseFeed(input, april21);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tell your coders to stop playing 3D shooters and do their jobs^^

Joking aside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var a, d, i, f, m, o, r, t, y;

a = [
    "2011-04-19 00:00:00 event1 title here",
    "2011-04-22 00:00:00 event2 title here",
    "2011-05-25 00:00:00 event3 title here",
    "2011-04-13 00:00:00 event4 title here",
    "2011-12-13 00:00:00 event5 title here"
];

r = [];
t = [];
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    y = a[i].substr(0, 4);
    m = a[i].substr(5, 2);
    d = a[i].substr(8, 2);
    t[i] = Date.UTC(
        parseInt(y),
        parseInt(m - 1, 10),
        parseInt(d, 10),
        parseInt(a[i].substr(11, 2), 10),
        parseInt(a[i].substr(14, 2), 10),
        parseInt(a[i].substr(17, 2), 10)
    ) / 1000;
    r[i] = [t[i], a[i], m + "-" + d + "-" + y + a[i].substr(19)];
}

r.sort(
    function(a, b) {
        return a[0] - b[0];
    }
);

f = Date.UTC(2011, 4 - 1, 21, 0, 0, 0) / 1000;
for (i in r) {
    if (r[i][0] >= f)
        document.write(r[i][2] + "<br />");
}
</script>
```

As the date parts of your input strings seems to follow [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, another solution would be to directly sort the whole strings literally (possible because chronological order would be the same as alphabetic order in this case), but that's another story and I'm not used to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sorting dates ascending or descending
times = ["01-09-2013", "01-09-2013", "27-08-2013", "27-08-2013", "28-08-2013", "28-08-2013", "28-08-2013", "28-08-2013", "29-08-2013", "29-08-2013", "30-08-2013", "30-08-2013", "31-08-2013", "31-08-2013"]
function dmyOrdA(a,b){ return myDate(a) - myDate(b);}
function dmyOrdD(a,b){ return myDate(b) - myDate(a);}
function myDate(s){var a=s.split(/-|\//); return new Date(a[2],a[1]-1,a[0]);}

times.sort(dmyOrdA);
console.log(times)
```